# configure lightdm greeter in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, login-screen

Earlier I was using the [not ugly] old styled login screen.
Recently have installed `lightdm greeter` to change my login box position from left to center.

Now, I have to configure lightdm to **disable** `guest-login` and enable `manual-login` in lightdm.

I have tried many tutors and steps on google but nothing change happened.

some tutor is saying to edit file ni `*/etc/lightdm/**` and some in *`/usr/share/lightdm/*`*

the files of these folders are as...

```
/etc/lightdm/

 - lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf [shortcut link]
 - lightdm-gtk-greeter-ubuntu.conf
 - users.conf
```

> ```
>    /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
>
>      - 50-greeter-wrapper.conf
>      - 50-guest-wrapper.conf
>      - 50-ubuntu.conf
>      - 50-unity-greeter.conf
>      - 50-xserver-command.conf
>      - 60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
> ```

I have tried making changes to all the files listed here but nothing special happened.

Also, tell me how to check for greeter-session, whether it is unity or gtk or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found answer to my problem and hope it will also serve best to the others who need it.

It's so simple. Just make some changes to .conf file and its done.

I had to make changes to two .conf files in order to get what I want.

**1. Disable Guest Login**

In Ubuntu 14.04 the .conf file to be edited has been moved to `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d` from `/etc/lightdm/`

run these commands :

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
```

add line :

```
allow-guest=false
```

**2. Enable Manual login**

since, in versions earlier than 14.04 .conf file is located in `/etc/lightdm/` directory which has been moved to `/usr/share/lightdm/lidhtdm.conf.d/` , we need to create a `lightdm.conf` file in `/etc/lightdm` directory

run this command :

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

add lines :

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
greeter-hide-users=true
```

**Thats it....**
Now, restart your pc and see the change.

**Screenshot...**
[image: Login Screen]

**[A full totorial is here : [Customise Login Screen NetPuppet](http://www.netpuppet.tk/2015/01/customize-login-screen-in-ubuntu.html%22Customise%20Login%20Screen%20%7C%20NetPuppet%22)]**